# Inserting partial ToC into \part

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, titletoc

I am currently just playing around with TeX and I had some questions regarding the use of `titletoc` and the `book` documentclass. As of now, I am creating partial small ToC after each chapter with the use of

```
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
```

which works wonderful. My question, is if it is possible to insert `\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}` directly into `\part`?

Comment: `titletoc` is an awesome package with which I am having myself great difficulties. But I think the answer to your question is that you should use `printcontents[parts]{}{1}{}` instead of `printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}`